# Going back to homescreen

Tags: java, libgdx

I adjusted an image for button and I have 2 stage on my game, one is homescreen and the other one is gameover screen. I put two button into the gameover stage, one is homebutton and I want to come back to the homescreen stage when I tap it, but there is a problem I couldn't solve. If we start playing game and immediately die, gameover stage comes and when I tap the homebutton screen, It works well(It directs to home stage). But If we start playing and play 5-10 seconds at least and die, gameover stage comes and when I tap the homebutton screen, a weird problem occurs. When I tap, home screen comes but immediately goes back to the gameover stage. I mean It opens home screen stage but comes back to the gameover screen right away. What is the solution ?

```
//home screen button
    Texture homeButtonTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("homebutton5.png"));
    final Image homeButtonImage = new Image(homeButtonTexture);
    homeButtonImage.setPosition(4*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/10,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/4+Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/22);
    homeButtonImage.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/12,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);

    homeButtonImage.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){

                    if(gameState == 2){

                        butonclick.play(0.6f);

                        gameState = 0;

                        birdY = 2 * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 3;   // Oyunu tekrar başlatırsak kuşun yerini ayarlıyor

                        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stagemain);

                        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
                        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                        stagemain.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

                        stagemain.getBatch().begin();                                                                                    // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
                        stagemain.getBatch().draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());               // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
                        stagemain.getBatch().draw(bird, birdX, birdY, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 10);
                        stagemain.getBatch().end();                                                                                     // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
                        stagemain.draw();

                    }

                    return true;

        }
    });
    stage.addActor(homeButtonImage);
```

This is the homebutton definition, onCreate part.

```
else if (gameState == 2) {    // Gameover stage




        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        stage.getBatch().begin();                                                                      // stage nin background u ayarlama
        stage.getBatch().draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());  // stage nin background u ayarlama
        fonth.draw(stage.getBatch(),"Highscore: "+String.valueOf(highscore),2*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/7,2*Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);  // stage üzerine bitmapfont yazdırma
        font.draw(stage.getBatch(),"Current score: "+String.valueOf(score),2*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/7,4*Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8);
        font.setColor(Color.RED);
        stage.getBatch().end();                                                                        // stage nin background u ayarlama

        stage.draw();
```

This is gameover stage definiton, if gameState == 2, it directs to gameover stage, I put it in Render part.

```
 if(gameState == 0){
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stagemain);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stagemain.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        stagemain.getBatch().begin();                                                                                    // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
        stagemain.getBatch().draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());               // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
        stagemain.getBatch().draw(bird, birdX, birdY, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);
        stagemain.getBatch().end();                                                                                     // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
        stagemain.draw();

    }
```

And this is the home stage, If gamestate == 0, it directs to home stage, I put it in Render part

```
 @Override
public void render() {

    batch.begin();

    // Drawing stage1, means home screen
    if(gameState == 0){
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stagemain);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stagemain.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        stagemain.getBatch().begin();                                                                                    // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
        stagemain.getBatch().draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());               // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
        stagemain.getBatch().draw(bird, birdX, birdY, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/10);
        stagemain.getBatch().end();                                                                                     // stagemain nin background u ayarlama
        stagemain.draw();

    }

    // -------------------

    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    // Game playing
    if (gameState == 1) {


        if (xKonumları[scoredObstacle] < birdX) {         // Score tablosunu ayarlamak. Eğer kuş, x inci engel sütununu geçmişse skoru 1 artır diyoruz.
            score++;

            if (scoredObstacle < 3) {              //0,1,2,3 üncü setlerdeyken döngüyü devam ettirmesi için bunu yazdık aksi takdirde 4 veya 5 olursa xKonumları[5] gibi bir engel setimiz yok.
                scoredObstacle++;
            } else {
                scoredObstacle = 0;
            }
        }

        if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {

            flapping.play(0.8f);   // ses kanat çırpma ve ses ayarlama

            velocity = -17;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

            if (xKonumları[i] < -Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 15) {

                xKonumları[i] = xKonumları[i] + 4 * distance;  // bu ne için ?

                engelBoyu1[i] = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); // boylarını random atamak istiyorum
                engelBoyu2[i] = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); // boylarını random atamak istiyorum

            } else {
                xKonumları[i] = xKonumları[i] - engelVelocity;
            }

            if ((engelBoyu2[i] > ekran / 16) & (engelBoyu1[i] > ekran / 16)) {
                if ((26 * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 200 + engelBoyu1[i]) + engelBoyu2[i] < ekran) {
                    if ((((ekran - (26 * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 200 + engelBoyu1[i])) - engelBoyu2[i]) > ekran / 6) & (((ekran - (26 * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 200 + engelBoyu1[i])) - engelBoyu2[i]) < ekran / 5)) {


                        batch.draw(obstacleup1, xKonumları[i], 26 * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 200, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 15, engelBoyu1[i]);
                        batch.draw(obstacledown1, xKonumları[i], Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - engelBoyu2[i], Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 15, engelBoyu2[i]);


                        engelBoyu1Rectangle[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/27,   26*ekran/200,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/160,   engelBoyu1[i]); // ortadaki rectangle
                        engelBoyu1Rectangle2[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/29,   26*ekran/200,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/110,   3*engelBoyu1[i]/4); // ortanın bir solu rectangle
                        engelBoyu1Rectangle3[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/36,   26*ekran/200,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/48,   2*engelBoyu1[i]/4); // ortanın 2 solundaki rectangle
                        engelBoyu1Rectangle4[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/50,   26*ekran/200,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/30,   2*engelBoyu1[i]/5); // ortanın 3 solundaki rectangle
                        engelBoyu1Rectangle5[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/83,   26*ekran/200,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/20,   1*engelBoyu1[i]/4); // ortanın 4 solundaki rectangle

                        engelBoyu2Rectangle[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/27,   ekran-engelBoyu2[i],  Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/160,   engelBoyu2[i]); // ortadaki rectangle
                        engelBoyu2Rectangle2[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/29,   ekran-3*engelBoyu2[i]/4,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/110,  3*engelBoyu2[i]/4); // ortanın bir solu rectangle
                        engelBoyu2Rectangle3[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/36,   ekran-2*engelBoyu2[i]/4,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/48,   2*engelBoyu2[i]/4);  // ortanın 2 solundaki rectangle
                        engelBoyu2Rectangle4[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/50,   ekran-2*engelBoyu2[i]/5,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/30,   2*engelBoyu2[i]/5);  // ortanın 3 solundaki rectangle
                        engelBoyu2Rectangle5[i] = new Rectangle(xKonumları[i]+Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/83,   ekran-1*engelBoyu2[i]/4,   Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/20,   1*engelBoyu2[i]/4);  // ortanın 4 solundaki rectangle


                    } else {
                        engelBoyu1[i] = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
                        engelBoyu2[i] = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
                    }
                } else {
                    engelBoyu1[i] = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
                    engelBoyu2[i] = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
                }
            } else {
                engelBoyu1[i] = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
                engelBoyu2[i] = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
            }
        }

        if ( (birdY > ekran/10) && (birdY<ekran) ) {    // bird eğer tanımladığımız sınırın üstünde veya altındaysa hareketi başlatabiliriz
            velocity = velocity + gravity;
            birdY = birdY - velocity;
        } else {                                        // bird eğer istediğimiz sınırın altına inerse 2 ye yani oyun bitimine yönlendiriyor.


            // To play hitting voice
            if(gameState == 1) {
                engelecarptıvoice.play();
                engelecarptıvoice.setVolume(0.7f);
            }
            // -------

            gameState = 2;

            // engele carptıktan 1 saniye sonra gameover music calacak
            Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    gameovervoice.play();
                    gameovervoice.setVolume(0.6f);
                }
            }, delay1);

            // ------------------
        }
    }
    else if (gameState == 2) {    // Oyun bittiyse sonra tekrar dokunulursa oyunu tekrar başlatabiliriz


        // Drawing stage 2, means game over screen

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);


        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

        stage.getBatch().begin();                                                                      // stage nin background u ayarlama
        stage.getBatch().draw(background,0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());  // stage nin background u ayarlama
        fonth.draw(stage.getBatch(),"Highscore: "+String.valueOf(highscore),2*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/7,2*Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/3);  // stage üzerine bitmapfont yazdırma
        font.draw(stage.getBatch(),"Current score: "+String.valueOf(score),2*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/7,4*Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/8);
        font.setColor(Color.RED);
        stage.getBatch().end();                                                                        // stage nin background u ayarlama

        stage.draw();



        if(score > highscore){      // highscore güncellemesi
            highscore = score;

            preferences.putInteger("savedhighscore",highscore);
            preferences.flush();

        }

        // -------------------
        //    +
        //   ++
        //  ++++
    }

    batch.draw(bird, birdX, birdY, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 15, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 10);
    font.draw(batch, String.valueOf(score), 100, 200);  // skoru görmek için yazdırmamız lazımdı. konumu x 100, y 200 belirttik

    batch.end();

    birdCircle.set(birdX + Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/25, birdY + Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/20, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/48); // kuşun circle tanımı


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {


        if(Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu1Rectangle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu1Rectangle2[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu1Rectangle3[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu1Rectangle4[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu1Rectangle5[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu2Rectangle[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu2Rectangle2[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu2Rectangle3[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu2Rectangle4[i]) || Intersector.overlaps(birdCircle,engelBoyu2Rectangle5[i]) ){

            // çarpıtıgı anda ses calacak sonra gamestate 2 olacak ve sesi kesecek

            if(gameState == 1) {
                engelecarptıvoice.play();
                engelecarptıvoice.setVolume(0.7f);
            }

            // -------

            gameState = 2;

            // engele carptıktan 1 saniye sonra gameover music calacak

            Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    gameovervoice.play();
                    gameovervoice.setVolume(0.6f);
                }
            }, delay1);

            // ------------------
        }
    }
}
```

I upload my render method

Comment: You should not be drawing anything inside the code of the click listener. That is the problem as I explained when you asked the same question a couple days ago.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yeah I know and for this reason, I really appreciate you.. But as you said, I tried to change if statements to switch case statement and put this code in render method but it continues to have a problem :( for example I have one more button like homebutton but it is for play again and it works well whenever I want, okay I shouldn't do it in click listener but what should I prefer ? besides as you said I was going to post this on libGDX forum but It does not accept to register. I'm taking this button's codes from onCreate and put it in Render but anyway I can't succeed :/

Comment: If you want something to happen exactly once, like playing a sound or changing the value of a variable like games are, put it inside the ClickListener. If it is something to draw or continuously update on every frame, it goes in render. Beyond that, we need to see your complete render method to know why it doesn't behave correctly.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I upload my render method, and before that, I want you to know that I really appreciate for your this helpful attitude

Comment: All those bits of code where you're drawing stuff in between your "if (gameState ==...)" blocks is always drawn. So you are drawing a background right after drawing gameState 0, which covers up what you drew. And there's more at the end of your render method where you're drawing some stuff on top of everything regardless of what the game state is.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I realized the problem and I solved finally... The problem is because of being outside of if(gameState == 1) statement for if(intersector...)